# Jquery DatePicker Set default date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I Have two date fields where I use DatePicker to pick the dates.

For the first date field, I want today's date as the default date.
For the second date field, I need `today + 15` days as my default date

**jQuery**

```
$("[name=trainingStartFromDate]").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', changeYear: true});
$("[name=trainingStartToDate]").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', changeYear: true});
```

How do I set the default dates?

I have tried `setDate: new Date()` for first date but it's not working.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Today date:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());
// Or on the init
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });
```

15 days from today:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", 15);
// Or on the init
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: 15 });
```

[jQuery ui docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)

Comment: I dot it same it shows in the textbox but not in calendar

Comment: @KushalJain, If you see this, it is likely because you haven't initialized the date picker.  You have to run "$( ".selector" ).datepicker()" before you run "$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());"

Answer (score 37):

To create the datepicker and set the date.

```
$('.next_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score 9):

For today's Date

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#textboxname').datepicker();
$('#textboxname').datepicker('setDate', 'today');});
```

Answer (score 8):

use [defaultDate()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)

> Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank. Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current [[UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat|dateFormat]], or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for today.

try this

```
$("[name=trainingStartFromDate]").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', changeYear: true,defaultDate: new Date()});
$("[name=trainingStartToDate]").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', changeYear: true,defaultDate: +15});
```

Answer (score 7):

First you need to get the current date

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

Then you need to place it in the arguments of datepicker like given below

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
```

Check the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unt8Y/8/light/).

Answer (score 5):

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
        $("#txtDate2").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date().getDay+15); });                       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code to display current date in element input or datepicker with ID="mydate"

Don't forget add reference to jquery-ui-*.js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dateNewFormat, onlyDate, today = new Date();

        dateNewFormat = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1);

        onlyDate = today.getDate();

        if (onlyDate.toString().length == 2) {
            dateNewFormat += '-' + onlyDate;
        }
        else {
            dateNewFormat += '-0' + onlyDate;
        }
        $('#mydate').val(dateNewFormat);
    });
```