# By default set specific date in datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I'm implementing edit user functionality. This is my jquery code for datepicker

```
$('#companybegindate').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy',
    changeYear: true
});
```

And this is HTML

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" name="companybegindate" id="companybegindate" value="">
```

My question is if I'm fetching any date from database , how can i set that date to datepicker by default ??

Suppose I'm getting '2016-06-20', how can I set this date to datepicker by default.
Any help is much appreciated..Thanks.

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580749/jquery-datepicker-set-default-date

Comment: You can use the PHP date function for default:  `value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"`.

Comment: have you tried to put the value in input field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" name="companybegindate" id="companybegindate" value="2016-06-20">
```

You may set date ('2016-06-20') directly to value attribute of input so it will be a default value.

Or You may use folowing to set it with java script.

`$("#companybegindate").datepicker( "setDate" , "2016-06-20" );`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$("#companybegindate").datepicker( "setDate" , "2016-06-20" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem be the option you search : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate. In addition be sur of the date format option too.

Answer (score 0):

you can add another property

```
defaultDate: new Date(2008,9,03)
```

to you object

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/1692/)