# Why is "defaultDate" not setting a date for my Jquery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1.  I want to set a default date for my date picker (today's date), so I tried the suggestion from this post --[Jquery DatePicker Set default date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580749/jquery-datepicker-set-default-date) , which suggested trying two things.  I tried

```
$( "#activationDate" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });
```

but although I can see a date picker when I focus on my textbook, there is no default value filled into my textbook when the page loads.  WHen I tried

```
$( "#activationDate" ).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Nothing appeared and no datepicker came up when I clicked on my text box. 
 How do I get a default value in the textbook AND have the date picker popup when I click on the text box?

Comment: The default date isn't put in the textbox, it's the initially selected date when the datepicker pops up. They still have to click on it.

Comment: can you take a look to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7srf64n/). I assume you missed or messed some libraries

Comment: @gaetanoM, yeah I didn't realize you have to call ".datepicker" twice, the second time to set the defautl date.  This is what your Fiddle demonstrates, which I didn'tr ealize previously.